# List of posts containing AI-generated text

Tags: discussion

In the recent discussions about AI:

[Should posts generated with the help of AI be marked as AI-generated content?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3018/should-posts-generated-with-the-help-of-ai-be-marked-as-ai-generated-content)

[How to warn users about AI generated content?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/how-to-warn-users-about-ai-generated-content)

I use an argument, that I have yet to see actually helpful AI-generated content on this site.

Instead of such [anecdotal argumentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_anecdote), it seems wiser to gather evidence. Putting the links to such posts in one place, especially if we decide to indiscriminately delete AI-generated content (and so remove it from search results), will make it easier for people to make their mind about the issue.

Using the below symbols can be helpful too:

**Q / A - Question / Answer**

- for a lack of a better idea and perhaps to be replaced by something better in future, Moon emojis with the lit part marking percentage of human input (bright is human)

❌ - post was deleted

✏️ - AI content was edited away (ideally the link will be updated to the revision which had the AI content)

**Currently new links are added to the bottom of the existing list, they aren't otherwise sorted.**

For convenience we'll add it here as well, we advise copy-pasting the [following snippet](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/how-to-warn-users-about-ai-generated-content) into any culprit posts.

```
> ### ![AI Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNrQD.png) Warning, Potential AI generated content⚠️
> **This post is suspected to have been generated with the help of an artificial intelligence, chat bot, or other language model tools without proper attribution.**
>
> There is reason to believe this post was not written by a human due to its structure, and grammatical construction, and has been marked by our community.<br>
> Current AI chat bots are a language models, that means they are like a parrot, they can mimic human language well, but they are built to write **seemingly** logical, **seemingly** factual grammatically valid text, rather than actually **be correct**, like a human would.<br>
> The veracity of the following content cannot be ascertained.
> See the [Concerns regarding AI generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396).
```

Comment: Nice, Ill try to keep this up to date

Comment: Good Idea. Me too.

Answer (score 2):

### Questions

✏️ [How do I Iterate over vertices to perform operation on them and connected verts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/298451/4)

[How to Apply Texel Density using Blender as a Python Module](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/301093/60486)

[Script to assign Color Attributes Color from Diffuse Material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/301598/60486)

[I'm trying to move vertices using an array but don't understand the correct syntax](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/302655/60486)

[subdivide_edges VS Loop cut in Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308974/subdivide-edges-vs-loop-cut-in-python)

[Batch processing scene render and a shadow not being bast](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/311214/newbie-been-struggling-and-cant-progress-batch-processing-and-a-shadow-not-b)

[Accessing 3d-print toolbox via a script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/311658/accessing-3d-print-toolbox-via-a-script)

[Link (With Driver) a Custom Property Value to a newly generated piece of Text](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/312259/60486)

[✏️](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/312429/2)  [Batch rendering multiple scenes using 'Material Preview - Viewport Render Animation'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/312429/batch-rendering-multiple-scenes-using-material-preview-viewport-render-animat)

### Answers

[Script not hiding/unhiding objects in render correctly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294449/60486)

❌ [VDM Joining objects together](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294331/60486)

[(Auto) Flipped Faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/293643/19307)

[Generate terrain from heightmap array](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/295699)

❌ [Watch YouTube video inside Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/295828/19307)

[How to Preserve Base Color of Non-Node Materials When Converting to Node-Based Materials?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/296970/19307)

[How to apply a Geometry Node to multiple selected objects (curves, not meshes)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/297308/60486)

[Blender boolean union breaks watertightness](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/299247/60486)

[What is unexpect behavior in rigify](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/299241/60486)

❌ [Why do the two surfaces seem to have a clear boundary even though they are the same color?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/299249/60486)

[Delete all measurements with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/301613/19307)

[What is the shortcut to add a new node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/302219/19307)

[How to loop duplicate one object on top of all selected objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/303218/19307)

[How can I "stretch" the time for timeline markers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/310579/19307)

Comment: I added a new link, clicked the previously added link to see what it is and copy-paste the warning from there, and to my surprise the post was written by the same user :D

Comment: Thanks for the update. Indeed from the same user, some things don't change. That is a good point. I setup a macro for pasting the snippet, but for convenience of whoever comes across this might add it to your post so users can easily copy paste it